# JQuery Selectors (finding cell in a table that's in a td)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have an HTML table

```
 <table id="sometable">
 <tr>
   <td>
       <table class="wTable">
            <tr>
                 <td>
                       <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" val="0" /> 
                 </td>
                 <td>
                       <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" val="5" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                       <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" val="10" />
                 </td>
            </tr>
       </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

The reason for the table within a TD is for the purpose of skinning and positioning.  I'm not great when it comes to JQuery and was wondering if there was a selector technique to get access to that radio button when that cell is clicked.

For example, previously my code was set as (before skinning):

```
 <table>
 <tr>header stuff</tr>
 <tr>
     <td>data</td>
     <td>data 2</td>
     <td><input type="radio" name="rdGroup" value="0"> No Warranty </br>
         <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" value="5"> 1 year Warranty </br>
         <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" value="10"> 2 year Warranty </br>
     </td>
     <td>data 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>footer stuff</tr>
 </table>
```

Above is the original basic table structure.

```
 $("#dnn_ctr391_Account_ctl00_ctl01_grdItems tr:first,#dnn_ctr391_Account_ctl00_ctl01_grdItems tr:last").addClass("info");
```

The above added a class named info to the header and footer of the table (i didn't care for any of the data in them)

From there I created a td click function to process data:

```
 $("#dnn_ctr391_Account_ctl00_ctl01_grdItems tr:not(.info) td:nth-child(7)").click(function() { //DO CODE HERE });
```

And within that click function I was able to access data from the other cells I needed:

```
 var warval = 0;

 warval = $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
```

Is there a way for me to get access using the same style of coding to get access to when that cell is clicked to get the radio button value, and then leave that table to go back to the TD it is in, and then get access to the other td's using the $(this).closest("tr").find() method?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think a better question would be about how you can layout your site without relying on tables for positioning. Also, if you're trying to expand the hit area of a `radio`, use a `label` with some `padding` instead of javascript.

Comment: Both your HTML and your jQuery selectors seem overly complicated - is there a reason to the complexity? Also, could you describe what effect you are trying to achieve? Your question is currently centered on iterating the DOM tree back and forth, but I get the impression that there might be a better way ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My area of expertise is Application Development.  Web Development is new territory for me.  I'm not the person skinning the site so I'll see if there's anything else he can do

Comment: @Grüse The complexity stems from the origins of this project.  I'm almost certainn there is a better way but this is what I was able to put together the reading and research I've done.  Currently, all of this jquery I'm doing is a customized add on that our client requested that isn't a part of our baseline web application that we sell.  In order to keep our web app standard so they can receive updates, we opted to add on this custom stuff through client side code that would leave the core functionality untouched.

Comment: @kmauzoul Ok, fair enough. Could you describe what is to be achieved in your code? Not in technical terms, just how your customer would describe it to you (let's assume he/she comes from a non-IT background).

Comment: @Grüse Basically, they wanted an extra column added to their cart (store checkout) where customers can select whether or not they want to add a 1 year or 2 year warranty.  The price would be reflected in the subtotal column as well as total column.

Comment: @Grüse Technical: I used that selector on the TD click to get the value, use an ajax webservice call to store that data in their database (as well as change the data in the subtotal and order total columns), and once an order is submitted, append the data to another table on the database.  If, for example a customer saves this order and wants to check it later, on the form load, i use what was stored in the database to retrieve the selected radio button, click it, and manipulate the subtotal and total prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, from what you said in the comments, I hope this is helpful:

First of all, I would advise changing the table markup to divs. This is not mandatory, but it will lead to cleaner and more manageable code. Something like this maybe:

```
<p>data 1</p>
<p>data 2</p>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" id="rdGroup_0" value="0" />
    <label for="rdGroup_0">No Warranty</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" id="rdGroup_5" value="5" />
    <label for="rdGroup_5">1 year Warranty</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="rdGroup" id="rdGroup_10" value="10" />
    <label for="rdGroup_10">2 year Warranty</label>
</div>
<p>data 3</p>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Your jQuery hook could be as simple as this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        // do whatever needs to be done here when the radio button value changes
        console.log("value '"+this.value+"' was selected for the warranty option");
    });
});​
```

If you need to set the corresponding value when loading the form with the data stored in your DB, you could do it with this function (if you've set your radio box IDs as shown above):

```
var setWarrantyOption = function(value) {
    $('#rdGroup_' + value).click();
};
```

You can fiddle around with the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gruese/fsj2v/

Please tell me if that helps or if I've maybe misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and see how it goes

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$('table#sometable table.wTable td').click(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).children('input[type=radio]').val();
    //To get 'back to the tr'
    var $warval = $(this).closest("tr");
});
```

Comment: I think you mean `.children`, instead of `.next`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  I added an alert just to see what would happen when I clicked anywhere in the cell and nothing.  Thanks, though

Comment: Did you modify the selectors to match your actual table id/class? Here is a working JSFiddle with an alert: http://jsfiddle.net/rdpTW/

Comment: Yes I have changed the name to match my table id's and classes but nothing fires when I click the cell.  I see it working perfectly in your jsfiddle but not sure what could be blocking mine.

Comment: Other jquery errors were stopping this from working, once I addressed those and tried this is worked (so anyone else that see's this doesn't get discouraged from trying it).  Thanks again